# Angular guard with http request

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

i'm trying to make guard, but i cant return value after subscribe
This code returns error `TS2366: Function lacks ending return statement and return type does not include 'undefined'.`

I checked some solutions and they using `map` instead of `subscribe`, but i'm getting this error `TS2339: Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Observable '.`

guard code

```js
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate, CanActivateChild {

  constructor(private auth:AuthService, private router:Router) {
  }

  canActivate(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    if (!this.auth.isAuth) {
      if (!localStorage.getItem('token')){
        this.router.navigate(['/login'])
        return of(false);
      }

      this.auth.checkAuth().subscribe(
        (data) => {
          if (this.auth.isAuth){
            return of(true)
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            return of(false)
          }
        }
      )


    }else {
      return of(true);
    }
  }

  canActivateChild(route:ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state:RouterStateSnapshot):Observable<boolean>{
    return this.canActivate(route, state)
  }
}
```

checkAuth code

```js
checkAuth():Observable<UserDto>{
     return this.http.get<UserDto>(`/api/user/refresh`, {withCredentials:true, observe:'body', responseType:'json'})
        .pipe(
          tap(
            (data) => {
              localStorage.setItem('token', data.accessToken)
              this.setAuth(true)
              this.setUser(data.user)
            },
            (error) => {
              console.log(error)
            }
          )
        )
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First of all, you code shows wrong usage for the RxJS and angular
2. Second, convert you subacribe to map, ie instead

   > ```
   > this.auth.checkAuth().subscribe(
   >     (data) => {
   >       if (this.auth.isAuth){
   >         return of(true)
   >       } else {
   >         this.router.navigate(['/login'])
   >         return of(false)
   >       }
   >     }
   >   )
   > ```

Write (notice return before, that's the reason for your error)

```
return this.auth.checkAuth().pipe(
        map(data => {
          if (this.auth.isAuth){
            return true;
          } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login'])
            return false;
          }
        }
      ):
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution! Maybe you can recommend some good guides for angular and rxjs? I don't have normal guides on my language(

Comment: Unfortunately not, I think it's just practicing